# How to improve a performance of the query to Firebase firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm facing a problem related performance using Firebase firestore.
The reason is recognized, but the solution is not found.
How do I cope that?

```
        const snapshot = await db
      .collection("customers")
      .doc(id)
      .get();
```

The size of a request is not a large, about below 10KB.

This image is a result at inspector.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing you can change about the code you shared to improve the performance. Your only options would be to get a faster internet connection (lower latency and/or more bandwidth).

From the screenshot it seems to take 53ms to read the document, which seems pretty reasonably to me at first glance.

Comment: Actually it's 53 seconds, but that might just be the time the socket has been open total.

Comment: Thank you for replying!
The time to response is not 53ms, correctly 53s(near 1minitute).
I think the code is reasonably too.
Do you have any idea of the solution?

Comment: >"the socket has been open total."   
Tell me more information about that. And how do I avoid?

Comment: Good catch Doug, I missed that. But in that case too, there's nothing in the code you shared that can be changed to improve that performance. --- If this document is loaded when the rest of the page is also loaded, it might have to wait until the browser has time for that call. To test this, wait for all other resources to load, and only then call Firestore to load that single document.